# Object null when trying to convert JSON string to object

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp

I am trying to convert JSON from this format

```
    [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "company": {
            "id": 19297,
            "identifier": "XYZTestCompany",
            "name": "XYZ Test Company",
            "_info": {
                "company_href": "zzzzzzzzzzzz",
                "mobileGuid": "2685633f-6375-43"
            }
        },
        "site": {
            "id": 1502,
            "name": "Main",
            "_info": {
                "site_href": "zzzzzzzzz"
            }
        },
        "inactiveFlag": false,
        "title": "President",
        "marriedFlag": false,
        "childrenFlag": false,
        "unsubscribeFlag": false,
        "gender": "Male",
        "mobileGuid": "afghgfdfgh",
        "defaultPhoneType": "Direct",
        "defaultPhoneNbr": "00000000",
        "defaultBillingFlag": false,
        "defaultFlag": false,
        "companyLocation": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Company",
            "_info": {
                "location_href": zzzzzzzz"
            }
        },
        "communicationItems": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "type": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Name",
                    "_info": {
                        "type_href": "zzzzzzz"
                    }
                },
                "value": "8",
                "defaultFlag": true,
                "communicationType": "Phone"
            }
        ],
        "types": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Name",
                "_info": {
                    "type_href": "zzzzzzzz"
                }
            }
        ],
        "customFields": [
            {
                "id": 41,
                "caption": "Type",
                "type": "Text",
                "entryMethod": "List",
                "numberOfDecimals": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 42,
                "caption": "Synce",
                "type": "Checkbox",
                "entryMethod": "EntryField",
                "numberOfDecimals": 0
            }
        ],
        "ignoreDuplicates": false,
        "_info": {
            "lastUpdated": "2015-10-03T05:59:47Z",
            "updatedBy": "Portal",
            "communications_href": "z",
            "notes_href": "z",
            "tracks_href": "z",
            "portalSecurity_href": "z",
            "activities_href": "z",
            "documents_href": "z",
            "configurations_href": "z",
            "tickets_href": "z",
            "opportunities_href": "z",
            "projects_href": "z",
            "image_href": "z"
        }
    },
    {
     more of the same 
        },
```

Into this format

```
    public class ContactJson
    {
        public List<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    }
    public class Contact
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public Company company { get; set; }
        public string site { get; set; }
        public bool inactiveFlag { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public bool marriedFlag { get; set; }
        public bool childrenFlag { get; set; }
        public bool unsubscrubeFlag { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string mobileGuid { get; set; }
        public string defaultPhoneType { get; set; }
        public string defaultPhoneNbr { get; set; }
        public bool defaultbillingflag { get; set; }
        public bool defaultFlag { get; set; }
        public string companyLocation { get; set; }
        public string communicationItems { get; set; }
        public string types { get; set; }
        public string customFields { get; set; }
        public bool ignoreDuplicates { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }


    }
    public class Company
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }
    }
```

I am parsing it like this

```
    var ConnectwiseClient = new RestClient("https://api-      aus.myconnectwise.net/v4_6_release/apis/3.0//company/contacts/");
    var request = new RestRequest()
    {
        Method = Method.Get,
        Timeout = 300000
    };
    request.AddHeader("clientID", "");
    ConnectwiseClient.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("");

    var response = ConnectwiseClient.Execute(request);


    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContactJson>>(response.Content);
```

The result object then has a count of 25 which is the amount of items returned but all of the items in this object are null

The result object then has a count of 25 which is the amount of items returned but all of the items in this object are null. When looking at the response object I know that the response isn't null.

Comment: Things like `public string site { get; set; }` and `public string companyLocation { get; set; }` don't much resemble your JSON, do they? In your JSON `site` and `companyLocation` are entire objects, not token (therefore not strings).

Comment: **Edit** menu --> **Paste Special** --> **Paste JSON as Classes**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `response.Content` is exactly what you say it is, then you have the following problems:

1. Your class is expecting `strings` for a few fields that are `classes`. Quickfix is to make them objects. For example

```
public object site { get; set; }
...
public object companyLocation { get; set; }
public object communicationItems { get; set; }
public object types { get; set; }
public object customFields { get; set; }
...
public object info { get; set; }
```

2. You are Deserializing into the wrong object.Should be

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contact>>`
instead of
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContactJson>>`

3. You're missing a `"` under `companyLocation.location_href` but that might be just in your SO question because if it was missing the code it would just throw istead of giving you `null`s

Comment: Why make them `object`? Why not make them something more directly usable like `JObject` (which is likely what JSON.Net will have populated those `object` fields with anyway)?

Comment: Its just a placeholder until you write the class. Because its more likely a newbie knows `object` vs `Jobject`